# Can an AMD Processor still be functional even if some pins were bent?

Tags: cpu

So i was upgrading my gpu and motherboard. upon trying to detatch the cpu fan, it came off with the cpu still pasted on the fan's heatsinks. noticed that a row of pins were slightly bent and prayed that it was still functional. it still loaded my pc fine, but performance of games have been significantly reduced. im 90% sure its not the gpu's drivers nor power supply that is the issue here.So is it possible that the CPU can still function fully with a row of pins being bent?

Comment: Well i just reinstalled my older card and the benchmarks are relatively the same (Still less than what it used to be able to run). doesnt that mean a ceiling has been hit and something is restricting the cards from performing at their greatest potential?

Comment: Did you straighten the pins before installing back in the socket?

Comment: i have not thought of that. let me try and get back to yall

Comment: So i have just straightened out the pins as much as possible and put it back in. it booted, but i think the performance might have gone down a bit. im not too sure at this point. i dont know if i straightened all the pins either because they're so freakin small

Comment: Yes;  Its entirely possible a CPU will continue to function, if certain Pins are bent.  They might be bent but still are able to make contact.  So identify the Pin(s) that are bent, there exists documentation, that provide a map of the pins.

Comment: sorry, i should have worded my question better. i was wondering if my overall gpu performance would drop should my cpu's pins be a bit bent around the corners

Answer (score 1):

A CPU benchmark would help you identify if the root of problem is your CPU. I know for a fact that not all pins are functional, some exist for redundancy and by extreme luck (it's a long shot when a whole row is bent :) ) you may have bent them only. Refer to data sheet for your CPU and it should tell you enough about purposes of those bent pins.

Answer (score 0):

If a Pin is completely disconnected, there are three possibilities:

It's a power or ground pin and is a Not connected Pin. In this case, there will be multiple ground pins that are all connected together inside the chip, so losing will have no effect.

It's a pin to a non-critical function. For example, it could be a pin connected to a status LED or a port unused.

It's a pin connected to a critical function. For example, something that connects to the memory or graphics processor, or an essential power pin. In such instances, you will have complete failure.

Check this page also.

[How to Fix Bent Pins on a CPU](http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-Bent-Pins-on-a-CPU)